# Модуль не имеет экспортированного элемента "Observable"

Tags: typescript, angular

Изучаю Angular и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

При попытке экспорта `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` получаю ошибку

> Модуль *** не имеет экспортированного элемента "Observable".

Пробовал выполнять `npm install rxjs`, не помогло.

Comment: У вас Observable написано два раза...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, где именно 2 раза?

Comment: какую версию rxjs вы используете?

Comment: @overthesanity проблема решилась после того как попрыгал с версии на версию rxjs. Спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score -1):

Введите это:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```